# How to load an image using openfl building for html5?

Tags: haxe, openfl, urlrequest

Hello i'm using this code:

```
var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest( "https://www.google.com.br/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" );
var ldr = new Loader();
ldr.load( url );
addChild( ldr );
```

to load an image and add to screen. It's working fine when i build to windows but i just can't make it work on html5, please can someone giveme a light with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot load it because or you are loading from another domain (CORS). If you open the developer toolbar it should note this. Try an image from your own domain.